# How do I rescore only those documents that have a tie (_score)?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a set of documents that match a certain query. On those documents, a rescore query is getting applied. Even after rescore, there are certain documents that are getting tied (having equal _score value). For such assets, I want to break the tie using another field (let's say a `date` field). How do I do it?

Tried following approaches:
1. Add two rescore queries: original_rescore, followed by date_rescore. This has the side-effect of changing scores of all the documents, not just the tied ones.
2. "Sort after rescore" is not supported in Elasticsearch.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "<MY_FIELD>": {
        "minimum_should_match": "2<-25% 9<-3",
        "query": "<MY_QUERY>"
      }
    }
  },
  "rescore": {
    "query": {
      "rescore_query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "function_score": {
                "field_value_factor": {
                  "field": "document.quality_score",
                  "missing": 0
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "query_weight": 0.95,
      "rescore_query_weight": 0.05
    }
  }
}
```

This query:
1. Finds all the documents that matches MY_QUERY (with MY_FIELD)
2. Rescore such assets based on the `document.quality_score`.

How can I add a sort/rescore to this such that all tied assets can be sorted based on a new query/field.